# @outlook.com email account in Thunderbird: "Your browser is currently set to block cookies"

Tags: thunderbird

I enabled two-step-verification for my Microsoft Account.

Now Thunderbird fails, and Microsoft emails me to suggest using an app-specific password.  No!  All I need to do is change Thunderbird to use OATH2 authentication.  It neglected to do so when I created the account earlier today, but I can easily change it Account Settings...

Except, when I try to log in, the OATH2 login window that appears for Microsoft says

> We can't sign you in.  Your browser is currently set to block cookies.

Can we fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit -> Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Web content -> Accept cookies.

I had disabled this earlier.  Oops!  I just needed to re-enable it.

You can always disable it once you're logged in.  So long as you don't mind that it will happen again, once enough time has passed and you've forgotten all about this :-).

### Alternative method

1. Edit -> Settings (or Thunderbird -> Settings on Mac)
2. Make sure you are in "General"
3. Scroll to the bottom.
4. [Config editor...]
5. Search for `cookie`

`network.cookie.cookieBehavior` was set to `2`.  If you reset it to the default value, `0`, then you can log in.